# Facebook android application requires login every time I open my application

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I have separate login fragment for login, when I click Login it goes to another fragment, that is my authenticated fragment which then show Facebook data. Problem is that whenever I open my application it open login fragment and every time I have to click login button to open my application.

how can I save session in preferences or cache.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch session directly by `Session.getActiveSession();` after login

Comment: I know this, but when I close application and then open it and call this function. It return closed state session

Comment: Did you clear session too?? may be you are calling  closeAndClearTokenInformation()

Comment: I have this function only in one place of my code, which is log out button.